# Jetpack Compose Column Composable Alignment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm creating a layout with Jetpack Compose and there is a column. I would like center one composable and the other to align to the bottom.
Here is an image of my target screen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLfDu.png)

I spent day working it out, `SpaceAround` and `SpaceBetween` didn't help.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Column with `weight(1f)` and `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center` to wrap the first item. Here's the code

```
@Composable
fun Demo() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(color = Color.Transparent),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .padding(15.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Green)
            )
        }


        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun DemoPreview() {
    Demo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom layout or something like:

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(0.dp))

    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp)
            .background(Red)
    )

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp).background(Blue)
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

[image]